# Rails 4: validate two type of users in a single User model using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I am using Rails 4 and Devise gem and my user model is called User (app/models/user.rb). What I want is to have two different type of users, personal account and business account to be stored in my user database table.

My user model looks like this:

## Personal Account Field Validation

```
validates :first_name, :email, :gender, :date_of_birth, :last_name, presence: true, if: :personal_account?
```

## Business Account Field Validation

```
validates :company, :zip, :representante, :founders, :founded_date, :address, :city, :country, :state, :sector, presence: true, if: :business_account?
validates_length_of :zip, minimum: 5, too_short: 'please enter at least 5 characters', if: :business_account?
```

In views/devise/registrations/new I have two radio_button to select between personal account and business account that I use in my user model to filter and validate the fields.

```
def personal_account?
 self.account_type == "Personal Account"
end

def business_account?
 self.account_type == "Business Account" 
end
```

I also have common fields between the two accounts validated by Devise. The common fields are:

```
 email
 password
 password_confirmation
```

I am able to create a personal account with no issues. But when I select the radio_button for business account, fill out all the fields and try to submit the form it will not work giving me a "can't not be blank" validation error on email and password fields.

views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb looks like this:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    
      <%= f.radio_button :account_type, 'Personal Account', checked: 'checked', wrapper_html: { class: 'radioName'}, data: {behavior: "clickable"} %><span class="ratiospace"></span><span>Personal Account<span class="space"></span></span>
          
      <%= f.radio_button :account_type, 'Business Account', wrapper_html: { class: 'radioName'}, data: {behavior: "clickable"} %><span class="ratiospace"></span><span>Business Account</span>

     #more code below
```

I do not want to have two different models for personal and business account because I am using a E-commerce gem who requires to have only one model who represents the users in my app. I also think that I dont need to create a role model because is already implemented in the E-commerce as the cancan ability.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to try a custom validator as shown here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

```
class UserValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.business_account?
      if (there's a field missing)...
        record.errors[:base] << "Invalid business account"
      end
    elsif (record.personal_account?)
      ... some other validation
    end
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with GoodnessValidator
end
```

Comment: Patrice Thanks for the answer but I tried and did not work. All the business account fields are validated except for the common fields, email, passowrd and password_confirmation. These common fields are validated when I create a personal account but not when I switch to business account and try to create an account. Really dont know what is going on? I think maybe could be the jquery that I call to hide or show the fields.